# Not able to set bottomnavigation tab icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable, android-menu

Im trying to add an icon to my bottom `navigation tab`,here is the code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_participant"
    android:icon="@drawable/car"
    android:title="@string/title_participants" />

</menu>
```

I'm able to add [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6qmc.png) image which is PNG image of `512*512 pixels` as bottom `navigation tab` icon but i'm not able to add [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t2vn.png) image of same dimensions as bottom `navigation tab` icon.
This is my code of bottom navigation tab

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_bottomview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier4"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: Whats your bottom navigation bar xml?

Comment: where is your showasaction property? of menu

Comment: sorry i have added it now in my question